# das Wort "autodidaktisch" und "I have taught myself."

Tags: translation, english-to-german, german-to-english, idiom

Meine Frage hat mit der Übersetzung von einem typischen Ausdruck auf Englisch zu tun.  Ich würde gerne auf Deutsch sagen "I have taught myself German". Eine deutsche Freundin hat mir seit langem erzählt, dass ich das Wort *autodidaktisch* benutzen sollte, jedoch habe ich mich niemals natürlich gefühlt, wenn ich sage "Ich bin autodidaktisch" oder was.  Ausserdem kann ich nicht komplett verstehen, warum der Ausdruck "Ich habe mich selbst Deutsch unterrichtet" nicht richtig ist.

Und wenn ich auf Englisch sage "I have taught myself German", meine ich, dass ich an keinen Kurs teilgenommen habe.  Ich benutzte Rosetta Stone, Podcasts, Gespräche mit Leuten, Bücher und die Erfahrung des Überlebens in Deutschland.

Also... wie sagt man "I have taught myself German" auf Deutsch, und warum ist "Ich habe mich selbst Deutsch unterrichtet" nicht richtig?

Comment: Höre auf dein Gefühl. Den Begriff autodidaktisch würde ich vermeiden. Kaum jemand nutzt den umgangssprachlich. Ich behaupte sogar dass einige Menschen nicht mal wissen was er bedeutet.

Comment: Man sagt eher ["Ich bin Autodidakt"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodidakt) als "Ich bin autodidaktisch". "Autodidakt" klingt ganz normal, in meinen Ohren.

Comment: I wouldn't use the word "autodidaktisch". I've never heard someone use that term to describe himself (or herself). The word is only used to describe other people.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, there are multiple ways to say "I have taught myself German."

If you wish to use the word "autodidaktisch", you can say

> Ich habe Deutsch autodidaktisch erlernt/gelernt.

Other possibilities are

> Ich habe mir Deutsch selbst beigebracht.
>
> Ich habe Deutsch im Selbststudium erlernt/gelernt.

Or (if you want to stress that you did it without help from other people)

> Ich habe Deutsch ohne fremde Hilfe erlernt/gelernt.

Your sentence `Ich habe mich selbst Deutsch unterrichtet` is almost correct. You just have to add "in"

> Ich habe mich selbst **in** Deutsch unterrichtet.

and it effectively has the same meaning as

> Ich habe mir Deutsch selbst beigebracht.

Comment: The Germans I spoke to insisted that using unterrichten for self-studies sounded weird.  Are you sure it's ok?

Comment: @artificial_moonlet Studying the Duden definition, I don't see a reason making *unterrichten* wrong for autodidactic learning. But it suggests information flow from more informed to less informed party so strongly, that it is not really used. While for acquiring simple facts it could have been used earlier, this would now be covered by *informieren*.

Comment: To me _unterichten_ sounds weird in this context. With _unterichten_ I strongly associate some student/teacher situation. So for me _unterichten_ doesn't fit if only one person is involved.

Comment: I think "Ich habe mich selbst in Deutsch unterrichtet." is acceptable and understandable (although the other variants are better). Duden lists "[...] als Lehrperson tätig sein; Unterricht halten" as one meaning of "unterrichten". So I think it is possible to use "sich selbst unterrichten" in the sense of being a teacher for oneself or giving lessons to oneself.

Answer (score 5):

> Ich habe mir Deutsch **selbst** beigebracht.
>
> Ich habe mir Deutsch **ganz allein** beigebracht.

Hiermit betonst du das Selbststudium.

> Ich habe mir selbst **Deutsch** beigebracht.

Hiermit betonst du, was du dir selbst beigebracht hast.

> Ich habe mir Deutsch **im Selbststudium** beigebracht.
>
> Ich habe mir Deutsch **autodidaktisch** beigebracht.

Das klingt beides schon arg gestelzt.

> Ich bin Autodidakt. — Das merkt man. (Oder: Hä?)

Comment: Und was mit "unterrichten"?  Ist es niemals möglich, wann man spricht über den Selbststudium?

Comment: Die eigentliche Bedeutung von *unterrichten* ist "das eigene Wissen teilen". *Ein Fenster im Klassenzimmer ist kaputt. Es ist zu kalt, wir können da drin nicht lernen. – Ja, ich habe die Lehrerin schon (darüber) unterrichtet. Sie sucht einen anderen Raum.* Sich selbst zu unterrichten (im Sinne von: sich selbst Wissen aneignen) ist daher streng genommen nicht möglich.